# su log file location

Tags: linux, logging, su

I prompted a failed su attemp in order to observe the log.
However, I couldn't find where su writes its logs.
My box is Kali 2019.
I commented out the SULOG section in my /etc/login.defs file

```
# If defined, all su activity is logged to this file.
#
SULOG_FILE      /var/log/sulog
```

Despite having done that I still don't have sulog file in /var/log.
I created one manually and made the wrong attempt again but nothing.

I am missing something?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

many times, login attempts or request for a new login shell are logged into os mailbox and/or on your system log.
It depend on your os default configs.

Try to check file:

> /var/spool/mail/

or try:

> journalctl -r

to see all your system log starting by newest